# connect ot MySQL from PHP problem

Tags: php, mysql, roundcube

Trying to install roundcube webmail - had some issues related to driver configuration - I'm now pretty certain the driver is configured ok now - i'm getting an error form it :

```
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond."
```

Now, this is from the following file:

```
<?php
// hostname or ip of server (for local testing, localhost should work)
$dbServer='localhost';

// username and password to log onto db server
$dbUser='*****';
$dbPass='*****';

// name of database
$dbName='roundcubemail';

    $link = mysql_connect("$dbServer", "$dbUser", "$dbPass")or die(mysql_error());
    print "Connected successfully<br>";
    mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die("Could not select database");
    print "Database selected successfully<br>";

// close connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

where the username and pass are good. In fact - i can use the same credentials to connect to the db instance through Toad.

In MSSQL you may need to tell the server to allow connections from remote machines and all that - but surely connecting through php is the same as connecting through Toad?

I've tried setting 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in case it's a case of connecting through the server name. Still no joy.

Is there anything else I may need to config to get this working?

Comment: You connect to a remote machine with *localhost* ? I don't understand.

Comment: it's the local host... i dont connect to a remote host at all.

Comment: user257493: where would i find the logs? would the windows logs contain this?

Comment: What operating system and version of PHP?

Comment: windows server 2008, iis7 - latest php (5.3.3. i think) - latest mysql too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the server to 127.0.0.1:3306 and it connected!!